# Disable Remote Debugging in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Yesterday I was debugging a service on a remote machine and now that I have corrected the problem I need to continue working on the code on my local machine. But now when I hit F5 the error "*The Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall...*" is displayed.

I checked the options under Debug - Attach to Process but there is no option to disable remote debugging.  How can I get rid of this message?

I also tried *Start Without Debugging (Ctrl-F5)* thinking I could attach to the process once it had started but I got the same error and the code wouldn't run.

I can debug other applications on the same PC - just not the code I used to debug the remote machine.  There are no changes in the project file but copying the code to another directory and excluding the *.vs* directory didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 created a `<ApplicationName>.csproj.user` file which contained the remote debugging information;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ProjectFiles</ProjectView>
    <PublishUrlHistory>publish\</PublishUrlHistory>
    <InstallUrlHistory />
    <SupportUrlHistory />
    <UpdateUrlHistory />
    <BootstrapperUrlHistory />
    <ErrorReportUrlHistory />
    <FallbackCulture>en-US</FallbackCulture>
    <VerifyUploadedFiles>false</VerifyUploadedFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <RemoteDebugEnabled>true</RemoteDebugEnabled>
    <RemoteDebugMachine>SXCRM:4024</RemoteDebugMachine>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Deleting this file or disabling the `RemoteDebugEnabled` property resolved the issue.